# Apache mod_rewrite problem

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to use Apache mod_rewrite to redirect some pages on my customer's website to the homepage. The .htaccess file is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^environment/teach-your-kids-to-go-green/(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/event\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/films\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/lastcomm\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/join\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^capturenature(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/blog\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^capturenatur(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/roadtomecca\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^capturenature/(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shopping/engagement-rings-for-men/(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/thecallhome\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^a3ff/stateofthings\.html(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For some reason, this rewrite rule - `RewriteRule ^a3ff/(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,L]`  - doesn't work on the production server. It does work on my development server, however. When I use `RewriteRule ^a3fff/(.*) DOMAINNAME/$1 [R=301,L]`, for example (one character appended), it works perfectly. It's probably the strangest .htaccess problem I've ever seen. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to accomplish?

The way you use `(.)` you can (and have to) only type exactly one character.
For example:

```
http://example.com/a3ff/X   => http://domainname/X
http://example.com/a3ff/    => Not matched by any rule
http://example.com/a3ff/ABC => http://domainname/A
```

What you want is probably more like

```
RewriteRule ^a3ff/(.*) [DOMAINNAME]/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Actually, I have (.*) in my rules, for some reason asterisk doesn't display here.

Comment: Ok, I guess they get eaten up as italic marker by the parser. In that case your rules are correct and I could test them fine. Perhaps you are hitting a bug with this server. However keep in mind that as the first rule is marked as L (Last) you can never reach any of the other rules that would also fit `a3ff/...`